# Collapsible Table in Markdown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have a table in markdown that I want hidden in a collapsible cell.

```
<details><summary>Open to view Data Dictionary</summary>
    |Feature|Format|Type|Description|
    |---|---|---|---|
    |**Id**|*integer*|Nominal|Identifier for each property.|
    |**PID**|*integer*|Nominal|Parcel identification number - can be used with city web site for parcel review.|
    |**MS SubClass**|*integer*|Nominal|Identifies the type of dwelling involved in the sale. Type is coded, please refer to full data documentation|
    |**MS Zoning**|*string*|Nominal|Identifies the general zoning classification of the sale.|
</details>
```

The collapsible format works. However, it is not rendering the table properly. Is there something missing from my formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not rendering properly because you are missing a empty line after your summary closing tag as it is explained [here](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab)

> NB: Make sure you have an empty line after the closing  tag,
> otherwise the markdown/code blocks won't show correctly.
>
> NB: Make sure you have an empty line after the closing  tag
> if you have multiple collapsible sections.

This is working for me:

```
<details><summary>Open to view Data Dictionary</summary>

|Feature|Format|Type|Description|
|---|---|---|---|
|**Id**|*integer*|Nominal|Identifier for each property.|
|**PID**|*integer*|Nominal|Parcel identification number - can be usedwith city web site for parcel review.|
|**MS SubClass**|*integer*|Nominal|Identifies the type of dwellinginvolved in the sale. Type is coded, please refer to full datadocumentation|
|**MS Zoning**|*string*|Nominal|Identifies the general zoningclassification of the sale.|
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I've overlooked

Comment: No problem ! Can you please mark the answer as correct so it is clear for everyone that it is working ? Have a nice day