# Docusaurus collapsible table in markdown

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I would like to create a documentation for a personnal project.
I am using Docusaurus v2 and I am struggling with collapsible table.

I know there are other topics relating this subject, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937284/collapsible-table-in-markdown)

I tried that

- with a line break after `</summary>`
- writing it in a **.md** and a **.mdx** file

```
<details>
    <summary>Données d'un <code>évènement</code></summary>

    | Nom                  | Champ          | Type            | Valeur par défaut   |
    |----------------------|----------------|-----------------|---------------------|
    | Identifiant          | id             | int UNSIGNED AI | -                   |
    | Type                 | type_id        | int UNSIGNED    | -                   |
    | Nom                  | name           | varchar 128     | NULL                |
    | Date                 | e_date         | date            | -                   |
    | Heure                | e_time         | time            | -                   |
    | Site de plongée      | location       | varchar 128     | -                   |
    | Niveau requis        | required_level | int             | NULL                |
    | Participants maximum | max_people     | int             | NULL                |
    | Contenu              | content        | blob            | NULL                |
    | Créateur             | user_id        | int             | -                   |
    | Date de création     | created_at     | datetime        | current_timestamp() |
    | Date de modification | updated_at     | datetime        | NULL                |
</details>
```

I always end up with the same visual table as it is in my code editor, with pipes and hyphens.
So yes, i feel abashed to ask it as i imagine the answer might be simple !

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
The issue was because there were 4 spaces indent before the table. They acted like a code block so that's why the table looked 'raw'.
So maximum 2 spaces indents (or 0 even better)